# SQL While Loop to retry Transaction until success

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop, transactions

I need to have a transaction, which when it fails, rolls back, and retries.

Where's what I have so far:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Save]
@MasterID as bigint

AS

BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
Declare @successtrans bit = 0

While @successtrans = 0
    Begin -- while
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION

                DELETE SomeRecords WHERE ParentRecordID = @MasterID

                INSERT INTO SomeRecords 
                Select FieldOne, FieldTwo, FieldThree, ParentRecordID
                FROM OtherRecords 
                WHERE ParentRecordID = @MasterID

                INSERT INTO AnotherTable
                SELECT FieldA, FieldB, FieldC, FieldD
                FROM MoreRecords
                WHERE FieldD = @MasterID

            COMMIT TRANSACTION
            set @successtrans = 1
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH

                IF(XACT_STATE()) = -1 -- Determine the state of the current transction (1 = committable, 0 = no active transaction (same as @@Trancount check), -1 = active, but uncommittable) only on severity 17 or higher
                BEGIN
                    DECLARE @ErrorNumber bigint = ERROR_Number(),
                        @ErrorSeverity int = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
                        @ErrorState int = ERROR_STATE(),
                        @ErrorProcedure varchar(100) = ERROR_PROCEDURE(),
                        @ErrorLine int = ERROR_LINE(),
                        @ErrorMessage varchar(Max) = ERROR_MESSAGE()
                    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
                        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
                    INSERT INTO ErrorLog(ErrorNumber, ErrorSeverity, ErrorState, ErrorProcedure, ErrorLine, ErrorMessage, ErrorDate)
                    VALUES(@ErrorNumber, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState, @ErrorProcedure, @ErrorLine, @ErrorMessage, GETDATE())
                END -- if
        END CATCH
    End -- while
END -- proc
GO
```

The question is, will this work for what I'm doing? Logic says yes. But this is a methodology I need to implement across 10 or more stored procs, and I'm having trouble making it fail and repeat.

Comment: What kind of trouble?   Please post the error or unexpected behavior you are getting.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, as I'm currently stuck on how to force the error in SQL, so as to force a retry. In production, the error happens once a month, maybe - a result of bitconverted guid to int duplicates.

Comment: You can use RAISERROR before commiting the transaction to force the error. You'll need a condition to decide when to raise the error maybe using a counter to force the error every once in a while.

Comment: This is somewhat unsettling. Can't you pin down the cause of the failure and resolve the underlying problem instead?

Comment: Thanks, @JonC, I shoulda known that.

Comment: @Biscuits, the cause of the occasional error is getting a guid, then bitconverting that to a bigint for use as a primary key. Because this application does this millions of times, both in C# and in SQL, we're starting to get duplicates, and the records are just being dropped instead of retries. This is a bandaid for about a month or two while I fix the underlying issue.

Comment: I will post the corrected sql when working.

Comment: I understand that a GUID is 16 bytes of information, while a BIGINT is a mere 8. Whatever "bitconvert" you're using would be prone to collusions. Can you not change the primary key definition?

Comment: I think this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow and would be better posted to Code Review instead.

Comment: I would be cautious saying it belongs on CodeReview. Code needs to **already be working as intended**. This sounds more like a feature request / validation / about unfinished code.

Answer (score 0):

You should check in the catch why it's failing or you could generate an infinite loop (Like already existing primary-keys).

As I don't know why you want to do this I won't say it's a bad design, but it's really suspicious. If it's failing is for some reason and exception message will say you why, instead of "brute forcing" your database until it does what you're expecting you should attack the cause of the problem (Bad data? Concurrency? Lot of causes could be causing the exception)

Edit: You should take care of your log too, on an infinite loop it will fill you hdd eventually